# Setting array.length to 0 triggers an error on solidity 0.5.0

Tags: solidity, web3js, arrays, solidity-0.5.x

Why setting array.length to 0 triggers an error ?

I have a function that deletes an element from a dynamic array of structs within a mapping as follows:

```
mapping(address => MyStruct[]) public structs;
```

My problem is that if I try to set the length to 0 it triggers this error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode

```
structs[_user].length = 0; // will trigger an error !
```

But: 
`structs[_user].length = 1;` will work fine.

It is inside a function like this one:

```
function _burn(uint index) internal {

  require(index < array.length);

  array[index] = array[array.length-1];
  delete array[array.length-1];

  // when array.length is set to 0 it doesn't work:

  array.length = array.length - 1; // doesn't work if array.length = 1

  array.length = 0;  // doesn't work

  // when array.length is set to a value > 0 it works:

  array.length = 1;  // works

  array.length = 2; //  works

}
```

I tried at least for 45 hours without findnig any idea why it happens! If you have encontered this issue or know how to handle it, help would be really appreciated.

P.S: I am using solidity 0.5.2

Here is the whole code:

```
// ----  Redeem a Stake ------  //

function stakeclmidx (uint _stakeidx) public {
require(_stakeidx >= 0);

Stake storage _stake = stakes[msg.sender][_stakeidx];

// See if the stake is over
require(block.number > _stake.endBlock);

require(_stake.amount > 0);

// transfer back token from contract to staker:
balances[address(this)] = balances[address(this)].sub(_stake.amount);

balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(_stake.amount);

emit Transfer(address(this), msg.sender, _stake.amount);
emit StakeClaimed(_stakeidx);

// deletes the stake
_deletestake(msg.sender, _stakeidx);

}

function _deletestake(address _staker,uint _index) internal {
require(_index < stakes[_staker].length);
stakes[_staker][_index] = stakes[_staker][stakes[_staker].length-1];
delete stakes[_staker][stakes[_staker].length-1];
stakes[_staker].length = stakes[_staker].length - 1;
// this last line is the one triggering the error
// it seems it triggers the error only when length value is set to 0
// stakes[_staker].length = 1; works !
// stakes[_staker].length = 2; works !
// stakes[_staker].length = 0; doesn't work !
}
// ----  Redeem a Stake ------  //
```

Best Regards

Comment: Get rid of the `delete array[array.length-1]`, it's redundant here.

Comment: Thanks for reply @goodvibration. Yeah I tried removing this line but array.length = 0; still triggers an error!

Comment: 1. Did you recompile and redeploy the contract? 2. What do you mean by "triggers an error"? What sort of error do you get? If it's a VM revert, are you sure it is not due to the `require` statement at the beginning of the function?

Comment: @goodvibration Yes I recompiled and redeployed. I get this error: Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert. I tried to remove the require but I still get this error...

Comment: Please verify that this error is not the result of the `require` statement. You could do this, for example, by adding a message to that statement (there are also other debugging techniques). I sincerely doubt that setting the array length to zero could cause a REVERT opcode.

Comment: @goodvibration I try with this function: _deletestruct(address caller, uint index) internal { structs[_caller].length = 0; } Just this trigger the error !

Comment: This function is internal; you must be using an external or public function in order to call it. You should give us the exact details if you want to get an accurate help here! Like I said, make sure that the error is not triggered by something which precedes your `length = 0` statement.

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. Give us something that actually compiles, with array defined and some clue about which mapped element to work with.

Comment: The array is defined it's a state variable. I just edited my question with more code

Comment: @goodvibration I just edited my question with more code. Do you see what is wrong ? Thank you !

Comment: After writing ~30 lines of code myself to get things to compile, everything worked fine as-is. So the rest of your code is probably more relevant than you think. As Rob asked for, please share code that _actually compiles and runs_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue in your code is bellow line :

```
array[index] = array[array.length-1];
```

You don't assign values to dynamic array. You need to push . Change it to

```
array.push(array[array.length-1]);
```

and then this should work. Just call reduce length twice.

Keep in mind that minus is very risky. After length is zero, it will not give error if you decrement again and it will cause underflow and a new array will be initialized with underflown length.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Arraytest{

    uint8[] public array ;

    constructor() public{
        for(uint8 counter=0; counter<2; counter++)
        {
            array.push(counter);
        }
    }

    event MESSAGE(uint _message);

    function reduceLength() public returns (uint8[] memory) {


            array.length--;
            emit MESSAGE(array.length);
            return array;



        //     array[index] = array[array.length-1];
        //     delete array[array.length-1];

        //   // when array.length is set to 0 it doesn't work:

        //   array.length = array.length - 1; // doesn't work if array.length = 1

        //   array.length = 0;  // doesn't work

        //   // when array.length is set to a value > 0 it works:

        //   array.length = 1;  // works

        //   array.length = 2; //  works

}

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! The problem with this method is that I can't delete a specific element from array unless I use loops. Are you sure about assignemnt to dynamic arrays? Because the method I try to implement seems to be used widely. Best reagards

Comment: Yes I am sure. I could not find anything related to this in documentation but I was able to replicate it with error of invalid op Code. Also, this only refers to dynamic sized arrays...Fixed size arrays may allow, will have to check. And yes, you can delete only last element

Comment: Ok thank you very much for information ! It's reassuring to know you were able to replicate as I suspected I had an issue from my local environment since other people said it was working... I will probably use a mapping instead as arrays in solidity have too much constraints. Best regards